# Distribution of order statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be independently and identically distributed random variables with mean $1\over \lambda$, find the distribution of the $1$st and $n$th order statistics using the joint density of the order statistics.

I find that the joint distribution of the order statistics is

$$f_{{X_{(1)}},\ldots,X{_{(n)}}}(y_1,\ldots,y_n)=n!\lambda^ne^{-\lambda(y_1+\cdots+y_2)} \text{ if } 0<y_1<y_2<\cdots<y_n$$

I want to know if this formula is correct and how to find the marginal distributions of $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(n)}$.

Comment: You are assuming that the random variables are *independent identically distributed* with *exponential distribution*. The problem as it is worded does  not say that.

Comment: Suppose $\Pr(X_1=1) = 1/\lambda$ and $\Pr(X_1=0)= 1 - 1/\lambda$.  Then your proposed joint distribution is wrong. $\qquad$

Comment: @AndréNicolas; Sorry for the OT: Can Order Statistics be used as goodness of fit tests? I mean, we can test how likely a given ordered sample $(X_1, X_2,..,X_n)$ comes from , say, a Normal Distribution, given the distribution of the $X_i$?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Could you please look at my comment above this one?